# Using BeautifulSoup to submit button/expand aria-expandable

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urlopen

Hi I am trying to expand the button on this [page](https://www.yelp.com/biz/lazi-cow-davis?osq=lazi%20cow) to capture the remaining attributes using beautiful soup. This is the html for the button I am trying to press:

```
<button class="button__373c0__3lYgT secondary__373c0__1bsQo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expander-link-content-cf6b4b45-8720-4627-96f8-397a766b8ddb" type="submit" value="submit" style="--mousedown-x:30px; --mousedown-y:27.625px; --button-width:113.422px;"><div class=" button-content__373c0__1QNtB border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"><span class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz button-content-text__373c0__Z-7FO text-color--inherit__373c0__1lczC text-align--center__373c0__3VrfZ text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B text--truncated__373c0__3sLaf"><p class=" text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B">15 More Attributes</p></span></div></button>
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}
url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/lazi-cow-davis?osq=lazi+cow'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

sub_response = requests.get(sub_url, headers=headers)
sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_response.content, 'lxml')

for item in sub_soup.select('section'):
    if item.find('h4'):
       name = item.find('h4').get_text()
       if name == "Amenities and More":
          tests = item.find_all('span')
          for span in tests:
              print(span.get_text())
```

I understand that you can use the Yelp API to scrape, but I need to do this with +1000 different yelp sites, so I was wondering if there was a workaround, as my current approach works (I will add proxies later), just not for all the attributes

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is mainly used only for webscraping and no more.

If you need to interact with a web-page, like clicking buttons, scrolling etc, you need to use a browser. **Selenium** will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button__373c0__3lYgT secondary__373c0__1bsQo activated__373c0__1moG8 ']").click()

for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class=' arrange__373c0__2C9bH gutter-2__373c0__1DiLQ vertical-align-baseline__373c0__3HGi9 border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU']"):
    print(x.text)
```

Tell me if this help.